# How can i implement the possibility of select an image on my app and send it to a remote database (JSON+PHP)?

Tags: php, android, database, json

i am creating an app that is like a mini social network app, with users, that can be friends of other users. Each user haves email, fullName, etc... but now i want to implement and give to the user the possibility to select a image from the images directory of the phone and make it his profile image.

That image have to be sent to the remote server and all the other users will see that image when open the description of that friend.

On my app i am using JSON and PHP to connect from my app to the remote database, then i supose that i have to transform the image into a String and add a row on the remote database representing the String of the image.

I have no idea of how to do this, and i can't find any easy help on google or here, all i am finding is too hard for me or is not what i am searching for.

Code examples are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not ever store a file directly inside a database field. The file belongs on disk in a directory on the server. A simple [how to](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql.htm). All that is stored in the database is the file location (a string) - this keeps your tables small and helps increase query read times.

To upload from Android you need to send it as a byte stream.

Some sample code

> HttpURLConnection conn = null;
>                        DataOutputStream dos = null;
>                        DataInputStream inStream = null;
>                        String exsistingFileName = "path_to_file";
>
> ```
>                  String lineEnd = "\r\n";
>                  String twoHyphens = "--";
>                  String boundary =  "*****";
>
>                  int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
>                  byte[] buffer;
>                  int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
>                  String urlString = urls[i];
>
>
>                  //get the file size here
>                  File f = new File(exsistingFileName);
>                  long fileSize = f.length();
>                  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
>
>                   // open a URL connection to the Servlet
>                   URL url = new URL(urlString);
>
>                   // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
>                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>                   //add the cookie
>
>                   // Allow Inputs
>                   conn.setDoInput(true);
>
>                   // Allow Outputs
>                   conn.setDoOutput(true);
>
>                   // Don't use a cached copy.
>                   conn.setUseCaches(false);
>
>                   // Use a post method.
>                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
>                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
>                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
>
>                   dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
>                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
>                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
>                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg"+ lineEnd); 
>                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
>
>                   // create a buffer of maximum size
>                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
>                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
>                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
>
>                   // read file and write it into form...
>                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
>
>                   while (bytesRead > 0)
>                   {
>                       dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
>                       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
>                       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
>                       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
>                   }
>                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
>                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
>                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
>                   // close streams
>                   fileInputStream.close();
>                   dos.flush();
>                   dos.close();
>
>                  //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
>
>                    inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
>                    String str;
>                    while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
>                    {
>                         Log.d(TAG,"Server Response"+str);
>                    }
>                    inStream.close();
> ```

Comment: this method is very hard, and i didn't know how to upload a file on internet. I simply have a direction and acces to a remote database, nothing more... i can't upload files onto a server, i simply can upload files into a row of the database

Comment: i mean that with your method i need some kind of acces to the remote server to write the image on it. And in the example code you put "how to" there is nothing about making the acces to the server to write the image